# Consuming REST webmethod returning and image

Tags: c#, image, rest

I have to consume a rest webmethod which returns and image/jpeg or png.

I use an HttpClient instance, and I guess I'll also need a MediaTypeFormatter of sorts. I can only see there's one for JSon and XML.

I have no idea what I end up with...I'd initially thought, that I'd get a filename, type and then a bytearray with the contents.

I can get the http response with Content.ContentType=image/jpeg, but I'm not sure what to do to turn it into something usable...

Comment: It would useful to help you if you put the part of source code :(

Comment: I don't think u can actualy return a image/jpeg from a httpClient instance?
I't must be converted to a bytestring in Json or others

Comment: Well...I haven't much more than
var response = HttpClient.GetAsync(request).Result;
And then I guess I need to know what to do with this HttpResponseMessage I get back.

For JSon I do:
                var httpResultStream = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                httpResultStream.Position = 0;
                var response = Formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(returnType, httpResultStream, null, null).Result;
                return response;
Where Formatter is a MediaTypeFormatter or rather a RestJsonFormatterProvider to be more precise.

Comment: I tried to run the request in Postman, and all I see is the image. Can't get any details that would be a clue

Comment: When I just have my httpResponse, I can see a byte array, but I have no idea how to interpret the contents...